# Refreshing an embedded image using HTML

Tags: css, html, image, src

I have a screenshare at work but the layout is wack.

I want to simplify it to full screen and nothing else.

Basically it screenshots the host computer screen every millisecond and streams a jpg via **http://10.50.0.173:7070/ScreenTask.jpg?rand=** after the equals is the jpg number.

All I want is a bit of code that refreshes the page or image every millisecond.

I have written literally nothing but the bare basics:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <img src=http://10.50.0.173:7070/ScreenTask.jpg?rand=" alt="screenshare">
  </body>
</html>
```

All this outputs is the image, if I refresh the page I will get the new image but obviously this requires a manual page refresh, not an automatic image refresh.

Comment: You want the page to refresh every millisecond? Is this necessary?
You could either refresh the page with a meta tag or use ajax to refresh the image.

Comment: Well every second then? See this is why I asked the question because I have little experience in HTML and wanted some help.